# How to print in log files Elastic Beanstalk in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using an Elastic Beanstalk environment in Python. How can I print e.g. values of variables in my application.py to the log files.
A simple print() statement does not work, and the logging facility for python also.
What are the steps to print a simple "hello world" in the log files?
Do I have to modify the requirements.txt oder the .ebextension folder?
When I deploy a .py file with errors in it and execute this file via cron I can't find any errors in Logfiles. But shouldn't be there errors somewhere?
I would be happy to get a solution how to print a simple "hello world" in my log files. Afters hours of searching I could not find a working solution.